# MPJ Express (Java MPI) running in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, mpi, mpj-express

I downloaded [mpj-v0_44](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/mpjexpress/releases/mpj-v0_44.zip) and extracted it to `C:\mpj`

Put Windows system env. variables `MPJ_HOME` to `C:\mpj` and in PATH added value `C:\mpj\bin`

I added `mpi.jar`, `mpj.jar` in Project Structure -> Libraries

[image]

and wrote simple helloworld mpi program:

```
import mpi.MPI;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MPI.Init(args);
        int me = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Rank();
        int size = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Size();
        System.out.println("Hello world from <"+me+"> of <"+size+">");
        MPI.Finalize();
    }
}
```

I created run configuration described on picture:
[image]

But I get the following error:

```
MPJ Express (0.44) is started in the multicore configuration
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at runtime.starter.MulticoreStarter$1.run(MulticoreStarter.java:281)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 0
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:122)
    ... 6 more
```

I found similar problems in eclipse posted but none solution worked:

[java.io.FileNotFoundException: null\conf\wrapper.conf (The system cannot find the path specified)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10697571/java-io-filenotfoundexception-null-conf-wrapper-conf-the-system-cannot-find-th%3E)

["Unresolved compilation problems" from running MPJ express in Eclipse Indigo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037871/unresolved-compilation-problems-from-running-mpj-express-in-eclipse-indigo?rq=1)

In Eclipse everything works fine but I need Intellij IDEA!

PS:
(if you need javadoc add whole `C:\mpj\lib` folder and `C:\mpj\src` folder for library sources)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to change the main class to

```
"runtime.starter.MPJRun"
```

and VM options to include your main class

```
"-jar $MPJ_HOME$\lib\starter.jar nz.geek.colin.mpj.Main -np 4"
```

This is because MPJExpress runs and then loads your program in order to create multiple processes.

If IntelliJ complains about runtime.starter.MPJRun not found you can ignore it but if the warning bothers you you can add the starter.jar to the project.

Comment: It worked just with adding class name to VM options  "-jar $MPJ_HOME$\lib\starter.jar Main -np 4"